# Use Opus Audio instead of Vorbis in Java Minecraft Resource Packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Can I use the Opus CODEC instead of Vorbis for replacement OGG files in a Java Minecraft resource pack?

Comment: Could you try, then answer with whether it's possible or not? This seems like something you can very easily do yourself, ensuring you make a backup of your Vorbis files in case it doesn't work.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because no game version is specified (Bedrock or Java, and both support OGG containers).

Comment: @Lemon Resource packs only exist in MCJava.

Comment: @FabianRöling On Bedrock for Windows 10, I have an option called "Global Resources", and they are still called "Resource Packs" on the [Minecraft Wiki Tutorials](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_resource_pack_add-ons).

Comment: Interesting, that must be new. I'm pretty sure they didn't have that feature before, because of some weird restrictions of consoles. It also appears from the wiki that it's only available on Windows 10.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.